# Is there a good source out there for commonly used datasets?

Tags: mysql, database, dataset

I just found the [MySql world dataset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/world-setup.html) which has saved me a lot of time.

I'm wondering is there a good source online for more datasets like this.
E.g. Common professions/jobs, etc.

---

*Preferably MySql*

Answer (score 0):

You can download [Jasper Reports Data Source Samples](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html).
They have them in various formats, one of them is CSV which should import in MySQL pretty easily.